# Load different subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have following ios app design:

I have segmentated control at navigation bar. When I pressng on different segments different subviews (with different controllers for them) should be presented at place of main view.
It's like tab bar controller, but with segmentated control instead tabs.

What the best way to implement this (I using storyboard, so if it can be done with help of ot it would be perfect)?

My app supports only iOS 5, so i need no compatibility with older versions.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to swap views, you could accomplish this by creating subclasses of UIView, dragging views into your viewController with the segmentControl, and then setting the views to the appropriate subclass. Check "hidden" for the views you don't want displayed initially.

Then, in your viewController, create properties for the customViews and create an action like:

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender {
  if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    self.firstView.hidden = NO;
    self.secondView.hidden = YES;
  }else if (self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    self.firstView.hidden = YES;
    self.secondView.hidden = NO;
  }
}
```

This will swap the views when you click first or second. Is that what you are trying to do?